# Swift combine add operator method,how to make return value simple and short,like Publishers.FlatMap<XXXPublisher<XXX>.XX> to AnyPublisher<XXX, Error>

Tags: swift, combine

When I add some operator,the return value will more long,like:

**Publishers.FlatMap<Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<NetResponse, Error>, Token>, AnyPublisher<NetResponse, Error>>**

In fact, I hope users only need to know **AnyPublisher<Token, Error>**  is enough.

Is there any way for me to only return **AnyPublisher<Token, Error>** rather than **Publishers.FlatMap<Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<NetResponse, Error>, Token>, AnyPublisher<NetResponse, Error>>**

```
public func singleHTTPLoginSignal(ccCode:String, phone: String, authType:String,password: String) ->  AnyPublisher<NetResponse<OauthToken>, Error>{
    return API.shared.combine_loadModelResource(GetOauthTokenAPI(ccCode: ccCode, phone: phone, authType: authType,password: password), type: OauthToken.self)

}

///Map:NetResponse<MQTTToken> -> Token
public func singleMQTTLoginSignal(oauthToken: OauthToken) ->
    Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<NetResponse<MQTTToken>, Error>, Token>{
        
    API.shared.combine_loadModelResource(GetMQTTTokenAPI(accessToken: oauthToken.access_token), type: MQTTToken.self).map({ response in
        return Token(oauthToken: oauthToken, mqttToken: response.data!)
    })
}


///AnyPublisher<Token, Error>
public func loginFullSignal(ccCode:String, phone: String, authType:String,password: String) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<NetResponse<MQTTToken>, Error>, Token>, AnyPublisher<NetResponse<OauthToken>, Error>>
{
    self.singleHTTPLoginSignal(ccCode:ccCode,phone:phone,authType:authType,password:password).flatMap{ response  in
        return self.singleMQTTLoginSignal(oauthToken: response.data!)
    }
}
```

Comment: `eraseToAnyPublisher`?

Answer (score 1):

We are using .eraseToAnyPublisher() for your case.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/erasetoanypublisher())